# CUDA : How to detect shared memory bank conflict on device with compute capabiliy >= 7.2?

Tags: cuda, profiling, gpu-shared-memory, nsight-compute

On device with compute capability <= 7.2 , I always use

`nvprof --events shared_st_bank_conflict`

but when i run it on RTX2080ti with CUDA10 , it returns

`Warning: Skipping profiling on device 0 since profiling is not supported on devices with compute capability greater than 7.2`

So how can i detect whether there's share memory bank conflict on this devices ?

I've installed Nvidia Nsight Systems and Nsight Compute , find no such profiling report...

thks

Comment: you should use nsight compute

Answer (score 2):

You can use `--metrics`:

Either

```
nv-nsight-cu-cli --metrics l1tex__data_bank_conflicts_pipe_lsu_mem_shared_op_ld.sum
```

for conflicts when reading (load'ing) from shared memory, or

```
nv-nsight-cu-cli --metrics l1tex__data_bank_conflicts_pipe_lsu_mem_shared_op_st.sum
```

for conflicting when writing  (store'ing) to shared memory.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is a problem, and is addressed in [this](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1045137/visual-profiler/nvprof-analysis-metrics-not-working-for-rtx-2070-cuda-10-0-/post/5310312/#5310312) post to the NVIDIA forums. Apparently it should be supported using one of the Nsight tools (either the CLI or UI).

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, **nvprof is replaced by Nsight Compute**, check [their metrics equivalence mapping](https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-compute/NsightComputeCli/index.html#nvprof-metric-comparison).

In particular, `shared_efficiency` gets mapped to `smsp__sass_average_data_bytes_per_wavefront_mem_shared` (cryptic!).

I have a feeling that more metrics suffered during this transition. Jokes aside, let's demonstrate how to use it. To this end, [take a kernel intentionally causing bank conflicts](https://github.com/Kobzol/hardware-effects-gpu/blob/master/bank-conflicts/README.md):

```cpp
__global__ void kernel(int offset)
{
    __shared__ unsigned int sharedMem[4096];

    int threadId = threadIdx.x;

    // init shared memory
    if (threadId == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4096; i++) sharedMem[i] = 0;
    }
    __syncthreads();

    // repeatedly read and write to shared memory
    unsigned int index = threadId * offset;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        sharedMem[index] += index * i;
        index += 32;
        index %= 4096;
    }
}
```

This kernel should cause conflicts unless the offset is relatively prime with 32. Call the kernel:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    int offset = atoi( argv[1] ); 

    // set bank chunk to 4, just in case
    cudaDeviceSetSharedMemConfig(cudaSharedMemBankSizeFourByte);
    
    kernel<<<1, 32>>>(offset); 
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

}
```

Compile with `nvcc bank_conflicts.cu -o bank_conflicts` and we are ready to demonstrate conflicts detection as follows

```bash
ncu --metrics smsp__sass_average_data_bytes_per_wavefront_mem_shared bank_conflicts 1 # ~ 99% efficiency = no conflicts :-) 
ncu --metrics smsp__sass_average_data_bytes_per_wavefront_mem_shared bank_conflicts 22 # ~ 49% efficiency = 2-way conflicts :-(
ncu --metrics smsp__sass_average_data_bytes_per_wavefront_mem_shared bank_conflicts 24 # ~ 12.5% efficiency = 8-way conflicts
```

As a bonus, let's establish the following fact: **every bank is accessed k = GCD(offset,32) times**, hence **the efficiency reported equals 1/k**. Why is that? A single int takes 32b = 4B fitting a single bank (the basic slice is 4B ); the thread x requests then the bank number `bank=(x * offset)%32`. This mapping takes every value exactly `k=GCD(offset,32)` times, seen for example by properties of linear transforms and elementary number theory :-)